# PrismJS: Centering Highlighted Lines Vertically

Tags: javascript, html, css

[PrismJS](http://prismjs.com/) is a syntax highlighter for source code in Web pages. It has a [line-highlight](http://prismjs.com/plugins/line-highlight/) plugin that highlights certain lines in the source code. In particular, that plugin supports determining what lines to highlight from the hash (e.g., `#play.5-6` says to highlight lines 5 through 6 of the `<pre>` element with an `id` of `play`).

For that hash, [the plugin uses `scrollIntoView()`](https://github.com/PrismJS/prism/blob/gh-pages/plugins/line-highlight/prism-line-highlight.js#L77-L105) to ensure that the highlighted lines are visible:

```
document.querySelector('.temporary.line-highlight').scrollIntoView();
```

(here `line-highlight` is added as a class to the lines)

However, `scrollIntoView()` puts the highlighted lines at the top. In my use case, it would be better to have the highlighted lines be vertically centered, assuming that the highlighted range is shorter than the available space.

What would I replace that above line with, in order to have those highlighted lines be vertically centered?

FWIW:

- While I'm OK with CSS/JS, I'm not an expert
- If it matters, my use case is to show this code in a `WebView` widget in an Android app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a function that will center the highlighted lines when scrolling (assuming that the scrollbar is on the `pre` element):

```
function scrollToLines (pre) {
  var lines = document.querySelector('.temporary.line-highlight'),
      linesHeight = lines.offsetHeight,
      preHeight = pre.offsetHeight;

  lines.scrollIntoView();

  if (preHeight > linesHeight && pre.scrollTop < (pre.scrollHeight - preHeight)) {
    pre.scrollTop = pre.scrollTop - (preHeight / 2) + (linesHeight / 2);
  }
}
```

Just call this function in the `appyHash` function *after* the `highlightLines` function is called:

```
function applyHash() {
  // ...

  highlightLines(pre, range, 'temporary ');
  scrollToLines(pre);
}
```

**Explanation:**

Just like before, the [`scrollIntoView()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) is invoked and the `pre` element is scrolled to the top of the first highlighted line.

If both of these conditions are true...

- `preHeight > linesHeight` - The height of the highlighted range is less than the height of the `pre` element ***and***:
- `pre.scrollTop < (pre.scrollHeight - preHeight)` - The `pre` element wasn't scrolled to the bottom (i.e., the current scroll position is less than the available scrollable height minus the height of the `pre` element).

...then subtract half of the `pre` element's height from the current scroll position and add half of the highlighted line's height. In doing so, the highlighted lines will be centered vertically if the range's height doesn't exceed the height of the `pre` element.

Basic test cases based on the live snippet that I was using when writing the code:

- [`#scroll.40-44`](https://run.plnkr.co/plunks/l3T0XbebTfIMb0MEwxAM/#scroll.40-44), [`#scroll.107`](https://run.plnkr.co/plunks/l3T0XbebTfIMb0MEwxAM/#scroll.107), [`#scroll.40-62`](https://run.plnkr.co/plunks/l3T0XbebTfIMb0MEwxAM/#scroll.40-62), [`#scroll.4-6`](https://run.plnkr.co/plunks/l3T0XbebTfIMb0MEwxAM/#scroll.4-6), [`#scroll.140-144`](https://run.plnkr.co/plunks/l3T0XbebTfIMb0MEwxAM/#scroll.140-144)

---

As you pointed out in the comments, this wasn't working for you because the scrollbar was actually on the `body` element (rather than the `pre` element like above).

To resolve this, change the logic so that the calculations are relative to the `body` element and window:

```
function scrollToLines () {
  var lines = document.querySelector('.temporary.line-highlight'),
      linesHeight = lines.offsetHeight,
      body = document.body,
      windowHeight = window.innerHeight;

  lines.scrollIntoView();

  if (windowHeight > linesHeight && body.scrollTop < (body.scrollHeight - windowHeight)) {
    body.scrollTop = body.scrollTop - (windowHeight / 2) + (linesHeight / 2);
  }
}
```

Here are some basic test cases demonstrating that it works when the highlighted range is at the top/bottom or if the height of the highlighted range exceeds the height of the window:

- [`#src.42-58`](https://run.plnkr.co/plunks/fRJsM7wDYi8juxKRwL4f/#src.42-58), [`#src.2-9`](https://run.plnkr.co/plunks/fRJsM7wDYi8juxKRwL4f/#src.2-9), [`#src.34-40`](https://run.plnkr.co/plunks/fRJsM7wDYi8juxKRwL4f/#src.34-40), [`#src.15-80`](https://run.plnkr.co/plunks/fRJsM7wDYi8juxKRwL4f/#src.15-80), [`#src.80-88`](https://run.plnkr.co/plunks/fRJsM7wDYi8juxKRwL4f/#src.80-88)

---

Since you may not know whether the scrollbar will be on the `pre` element or the `body`, you could check if the `pre` element is scrollable first and then fall back to making the calculations relative to the `body` element if it isn't:

```
function scrollToLines (pre) {
  var lines = document.querySelector('.temporary.line-highlight'),
      linesHeight = lines.offsetHeight,
      pre = pre.scrollHeight > pre.clientHeight ? pre : document.body,
      preHeight = pre === document.body ? window.innerHeight : pre.offsetHeight;

  lines.scrollIntoView();

  if (preHeight > linesHeight && pre.scrollTop < (pre.scrollHeight - preHeight)) {
    pre.scrollTop = pre.scrollTop - (preHeight / 2) + (linesHeight / 2);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, `pre.offsetHeight` seems to be always equal to `pre.scrollHeight`, and `pre.scrollTop` is always 0. As a result, `pre.scrollTop < (pre.scrollHeight - preHeight)` always fails, and I wind up with just `scrollIntoView()` behavior. See https://run.plnkr.co/plunks/VNETsv4GoY388YjsbCJr/#src.4-10 and other ranges.

Comment: I can see the results working in Plunkr. However, as I have never heard of Plunkr before today and can't figure out if/how I can do a diff, can you explain, briefly, what exactly you changed in the CSS? Or, just ping me back if and when you update the answer (per your edited comment above). Thanks!

Comment: @CommonsWare I actually didn't change anything but the CSS, so I'm not sure why that didn't work. I updated my answer and provided a function for if the scrollbar is on the `body` element (rather than the `pre`). Since that may not be flexible enough (since you may not know which element has a scrollbar), I added an additional function that will check if the scrollbar is on the `pre` element and then fallback to making the calculations relative to the `body` element if it isn't. It works in the test cases I linked to using your code, so hopefully it works for you offline.

Comment: Your middle chunk of code is back to the original problem. `body.scrollTop < (body.scrollHeight - windowHeight)` is `false` (`body.scrollTop` is 8, `body.scrollHeight` is 762, `windowHeight` is 754, and 8 is not < 8). If I change it to `<=`, then `body.scrollTop` winds up 0, because negative numbers are not allowed, and `windowHeight` is 754. To help eliminate Plunkr issues, here's what I am testing with: https://commonsware.com/misc/prism/MainActivity.java.html#src.50-59 The final chunk of code seems to have similar issues.

Comment: @CommonsWare On line 53 in prism.css, change `height: 100%` to `min-height: 100%` (it is added with the selector `code[class*="language"]`).

Comment: That helped a lot! The changed files are at that URL still. What's still not quite working are highlights towards the bottom of the file (e.g., https://commonsware.com/misc/prism/MainActivity.java.html#src.76-86). We're far enough down that we can no longer center vertically, but the lines do not completely scroll into view.

Comment: @CommonsWare That's because you changed `<` to `<=`. Revert it back to what I have above and it will work.

Comment: Mea culpa! Sorry, I had forgotten about that. That does seem to clear things up. Many, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If it's ok using jQuery you could use something like this:

```js
function goToHighLight(selector, container){
    document.querySelector(selector).scrollIntoView();
    var scroll = document.querySelector(container).clientHeight ;
    var half_scroll = scroll/2;
    
    var selector_h = document.querySelector(selector).clientHeight/2;

    var next = 0;
    $(selector).nextAll().each(function( index ) {
      next += this.clientHeight;
    });

    var prev = 0;
    $(selector).prevAll().each(function( index ) {
      prev += this.clientHeight;
    });
    if(next < half_scroll){
      var diff = half_scroll-next-selector_h;
      $(container).children().last().css("margin-bottom",diff);
      var where_am_i = $(container).scrollTop();
      $(container).scrollTop(where_am_i+diff);
    }
    
    else if(prev < half_scroll){
      var diff = half_scroll-prev-selector_h;
      $(container).children().first().css("margin-top",diff);
      var where_am_i = $(container).scrollTop();
      $(container).scrollTop(where_am_i-diff);
    }
    else{
      var where_am_i = $(container).scrollTop();
      $(container).scrollTop(where_am_i-half_scroll+selector_h);
    }

}

goToHighLight("#highlight4", "#container");

$(".goH").click(function(){
    goToHighLight("#"+this.id,"#container");
});
```

```css
#container{
  width:250px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  float:left;
}
.foo{
  width:250px;
  height: 600px;
  display:block;
  background:grey;
}
.bar{
  width:250px;
  height: 100px;
  display:block;
  background:yellow;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.highlight{
  width:250px;
  background:green;
}
#buttons{
  float:left;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="highlight" id="highlight1">
   highlight, highlight, highlight<br>
   highlight, highlight, highlight<br>
   highlight, highlight, highlight<br>
  highlight, highlight, highlight<br>
  highlight, highlight, highlight
  </div>
  <div class="bar">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. <br> Fusce dolor ante, luctus ut nibh in, ultrices eleifend elit. 
  </div>
   <div class="highlight" id="highlight2">
   highlight2, highlight2, highlight2<br>
   highlight2, highlight2, highlight2
  </div>
  <div class="bar">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. <br> Fusce dolor ante, luctus ut nibh in, ultrices eleifend elit. 
  </div>
   <div class="highlight" id="highlight3">
   highlight3, highlight3, highlight3<br>
   highlight3, highlight3, highlight3<br>
   highlight3, highlight3, highlight3
  </div>
  <div class="foo">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. <br> Fusce dolor ante, luctus ut nibh in, ultrices eleifend elit. 
  </div>
  <div class="foo">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. <br> Fusce dolor ante, luctus ut nibh in, ultrices eleifend elit. 
  </div>
  <div class="foo">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. <br> Fusce dolor ante, luctus ut nibh in, ultrices eleifend elit. 
  </div>
  <div class="foo">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. <br> Fusce dolor ante, luctus ut nibh in, ultrices eleifend elit. 
  </div>
  <div class="foo">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. <br> Fusce dolor ante, luctus ut nibh in, ultrices eleifend elit. 
  </div>
  <div class="highlight" id="highlight4">
   highlight4, highlight4, highlight4<br>
   highlight4, highlight4, highlight4<br>
   highlight4, highlight4, highlight4<br>
  highlight4, highlight4, highlight4<br>
  highlight4, highlight4, highlight4<br>
  highlight4, highlight4, highlight4<br>
  highlight4, highlight4, highlight4
  </div>
  <div class="bar">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. <br> Fusce dolor ante, luctus ut nibh in, ultrices eleifend elit. 
  </div>
  <div class="highlight" id="highlight5">
  highlight5, highlight5, highlight5<br>
  highlight5, highlight5, highlight5<br>
  highlight5, highlight5, highlight5<br>
  highlight5, highlight5, highlight5<br>
  highlight5, highlight5, highlight5<br>
  
  </div>
</div>
<div id="buttons">
  <button class="goH" id="highlight1">
    highlight1
  </button>
  <button class="goH" id="highlight2">
    highlight2
  </button>
  <button class="goH" id="highlight3">
    highlight3
  </button>
  <button class="goH" id="highlight4">
    highlight4
  </button>
  <button class="goH" id="highlight5">
    highlight5
  </button>
</div>
```

Try to place the `highlight` div in different places.

Comment: OK, if I use that script, replacing `container` with an `id` I slapped on the `<code>` element that wraps the source code being formatted, it mostly works. For some reason, it's coming in a bit low, as if `scrollTop()` is over-adjusting. The top of the highlighted area appears about two-thirds of the way down the page. Thanks!

Comment: However, your approach breaks if the content cannot be scrolled far enough to be centered. In your fiddle, if you move the `highlight` `<div>` to the bottom (after the `bar` `<div>`), the highlight does not wind up being shown.

Comment: that's true... you have to check if the offset previous the `highlight` or after to it it's higher than the scroll... let me edit the answer with another approach

Comment: This does not work with the PrismJS line-highlight plugin, at least in terms of how I tried to integrate it, replacing `#highlight` with either `#line-highlight` or `#temporary.line-highlight`, and replacing `container` with `src2` (the id of my `<code>` element that wraps the source code to be formatted). I don't need a JavaScript solution that works with arbitrary HTML. I need a JavaScript(?) solution that works with PrismJS and its line-highlight plugin. Thanks, though!

Comment: well, I have never used PrismJS, if you share a example of your code maybe I can help you ;)